# Image upload modify file

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

I've created a Magento module which should hook into an event when a file is saved to cache. But it looks like there isn't any event like that, or am I missing something?

I currently hooked up with the

> category_product_gallery_upload_image_after

but then the file is edited by magento before writing to cache because it's resized. Therefor overwriting my file optimalisation.

Is there any way I can hook to an image before it's written to cache, or after the resizing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no native function or event for this.

But you can done by rewrite the image save function [Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image::save file()](https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Image.php#L481-L487)

i.e.,

```
public function saveFile() { 
   $filename = $this->getNewFile();
   $this->getImageProcessor()->save($filename); 
   //you can do your logic here.
    Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->saveFile($filename);
    return $this; 
}
```

Comment: That is the place when it's saved to the cache?

Comment: Yes, to resize product image we have use following code `Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product,'image')->resize(500)`. So in this function they have save the image using above function.